# Visual Studio: Is there a setting to delete whitespace a tab at a time?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm using the latest VS Community.  Let's say my cursor is right here:

[image]

When I press delete, a space is deleted.  Is there a way to make it so four spaces are deleted instead?  That's the way it works in a lot of other editors, including VS Code.

Comment: Use shift-tab to go back a tab.

Comment: @alans that's useful.  I'm still hoping there's a way where I don't have to change my behavior and I can just press delete.

Comment: Well before you mentioned it, I never knew pressing backspace would go back a tab as well. We all learn something new!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I press delete, a space is deleted. Is there a way to make it so four spaces are deleted instead? That's the way it works in a lot of other editors, including VS Code.

Many editors including *Visual Studio* (VS), can be configured to show tab characters either **as tabs** or rendered to a fixed **number of spaces**, say four (4).  (there are reasons for this, each with their own pros and cons - a subject for another day)

I suspect what you were seeing in *VS Code* (VSC) was a file that contained a tab character and VSC is showing *tabs as tabs* (instead of spaces) in the text editor.  Hitting <kbd>Delete</kbd> over a tab makes it look like four spaces get deleted in one go!

However, your installation of Visual Studio however might be set to show tabs **as spaces** (I forget which is the default) which explains why you have to hit <kbd>Delete</kbd> more than once over an area of indentation.

You can confirm how tabs are shown in VS by selecting **Edit.Advanced.View White Space** (I like to keep it on).  If you see little arrows it means a tab character is present.  If you see dim period symbols its a space.  In the screenshot below we can see a file with tabs rendered as spaces.

[image]

If tabs are rendered as spaces in VS that explains why you have to press the key four times.

You can control whether you want to always have tabs or spaces by selecting **Tools.Options.Text Editor.C#.Tabs** (assuming the file is C#)

[image]

Once this is setup "tabs" will either be tabs or 'n' number of spaces.  However **this only applies for new documents** and VS generally doesn't auto-tabify-on-save.

Now it would be rather tedius to go through every file, manually flip everything to tabbed format so luckily VS has a rather neat feature to convert a file to tab or spaces based on your options:

1. In **Options** specify whether that you want tabs
2. open the file in question (say a C# file).  Looks like the following image (yuck! spaces!):

[image]

3. Select **Edit.Advanced.Format Document**

[image]

4. document is now tabbed.  Delete what you want. Repeat 2-4 as required.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response.  I'll go with this if it's the only option, but I was hoping there's an option to treat the spaces as tabs when pressing delete, but actually have them be spaces in the file.  This is the way intellij idea works by default.  See, I'm a spaces guy, but I don't like how many key presses it takes to delete blank lines, *and* I'm used to pressing delete to delete 4 spaces at once if the line is blank.  Can VS give me what I'm used to in intellij?  If not, this is the next best thing.

Comment: @DanielKaplan Thanks! Yes agree that would have been awesome if VS did that.  I've heard many great things about Jetbrain's IntelliJ so much so that was the inspiration by Jetbrains for R# I believe.  If anything can do that delete spaces thing in VS I suspect we would need to have R# installed but I'm not aware of R# having that feature sadly.

Comment: Tabs are never "rendered as spaces" or vice versa.

The indentation setting determines the behavior of indentation when hitting the return key.  The tabs setting determines both the width of the tab character, and the size of each indentation.  I cannot for the life of me figure out why anyone would want these to be different, but: if indentation is set to '13', for example, and tab is set to '5', then a first-level indentation would insert two tabs and three spaces.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/options-text-editor-all-languages-tabs?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 3):

The only built-in way to delete spaces just like they were tabs is to shift-TAB.  Otherwise there is a plug-in called TabSanity that does what you want: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jedmao.TabSanity-10817

Turning on Visual Studio's "View White Space" (toggle with CTRL-R, CTRL-W) always shows what's in the file; it never "renders" tabs as spaces or vice versa.

[image: "Keep tabs"]

Comment: _"it never "renders" tabs as spaces"_ - perhaps, perhaps not. When you consider the OP's title of  _"Is there a setting to delete whitespace a `tab` at a time?"_ and the statement _"When I press delete, a space is deleted. Is there a way to make it so `four spaces` are deleted instead? "_, it seems pretty evident that in the OP's and my mind that what we're looking at is a representation of _indentation_ typically associated with a **Tab**.  If this were not the case, one would not expect it to magically delete say 4 spaces.  Or for a 3rd party tool for that matter

Comment: The amount of horizontal space a tab takes up is not necessarily the same as how much horizontal space an indentation takes up, and the "Keep tabs" feature does its best to maximize the number of tab characters used when indenting, as when formatting or pressing ENTER or TAB.  I think that your preference for tabs, as well as keeping the "Tab size" and "Indent size" set to the same value, may cause you to conflate the two, but it doesn't make true the statement that Visual Studio can be set "to show tabs as spaces".  I cannot discern this confusion by the OP.

Comment: @MickyD Why would we not "not expect it to magically delete say 4 spaces"?  This is a very easy behavior to implement, and many editors (including VS Code) have no problem with it.

Comment: So we agree then, tabs are rendered as spaces.  That or we are discussing two completely different things.  We'll have to agree to disagree

Comment: I think we agree, except that you're erroneously using the word "render" to mean "insert", as in "the IDE *inserts* tabs as spaces".  This has quite a different meaning from "the IDE renders tabs [characters] as spaces", which only makes sense to say when "View white space" is on (except that it's not true).